# angular add a sum column

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

How do we insert a column in an angular table , for example based on the screenshot I want to add Total text below the last value of the    Rent ($/SF) , I tried adding tr , td and mat footer cell but it does not work . Any idea guys ? Thanks. Appreaciated.

how to add a total which is just a text below the last value of the     Rent ($/SF) ???

I tried <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> Total  but it does not work.

[image]

#html code

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="bovRentComsCompleted" class="mat-elevation-z0">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let p of rentCompsTableLabel; last as l" matColumnDef="{{p.key}}">
                  <th [ngClass]="{'th-rents-completed-min-width':!l}" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="fs-12px">{{p.label}}</th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; index as i"
                    [ngClass]="{'border-none': i === bovRentComsCompleted.length - 1}" class="fs-12px">
                    <span *ngIf="p.key === 'rent'">{{element[p.key] != null ? '$' : ''}}{{element[p.key] !== null ? (element[p.key] | number : '1.2-2') : '-'}}</span>
                    <span *ngIf="p.key === 'distanceFromWag'">{{element[p.key] !== null ? (element[p.key] | number : '1.2-2') : '-'}}</span>
                    <span *ngIf="p.key === 'quality'">{{element[p.key] !== null ? (element[p.key]) : '-'}}</span>
                    <mat-slide-toggle [disabled]="true" [(ngModel)]="element[p.key]" *ngIf="p.key === 'isTls'" color="primary"></mat-slide-toggle>
                    <span *ngIf="p.key === 'address'">{{element[p.key] !== null ? (element[p.key]) : '-'}}</span>
                    <span *ngIf="p.key === 'leaseStart'">{{element[p.key] !== null ? (element[p.key] | date : 'MM/dd/yyyy') : '-'}}</span>
                    <span *ngIf="p.key === 'sf'">{{element[p.key] !== null ? (element[p.key] | number) : '-'}}</span>
                    <span *ngIf="p.key === 'notes'">{{element[p.key] !== null ? (element[p.key]) : '-'}}</span>
                  </td>
                </ng-container>
                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableRentComps"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableRentComps;" class="cursor-default">
                </tr>
              </table>
```

Comment: It would be good to simplify your problem. Also here is a good resource https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-find-sum-of-table-column-in-angular-10/

Comment: My concern is just how to add a total column below , that's basically it

Comment: You should check the angular material documentation - there is description what you should do and also a demo to view it https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#footer-row

Comment: You should add the title of your new columns to the mat-table data source.
For the above code, you should write it in "bovRentComsCompleted" and in the response(rentCompsTableLabel) you need that value of the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let total = 0;
let value = 0;

ngOnInit(): void {  
    this.findSum();  
}  

findSum(data) {
  for(d in data) {
    total += data.value;
  }
  
  return total;
}
```

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="data">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="sum">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Total: </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let d"> {{d.total}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  
</table>
```